# How to use USART interrupt char variable in main code?

Tags: c, pic, mplab

I am using PIC18F4550, and following the example given in https://www.electronicwings.com/pic/pic18f4550-usart, the program works because  when i send a character via bluetooth (HC05) it received it and then transmit the same character, the problem is, that is done in the interrupt USART function and if i try to compare the character received in the main code for example

if(data == 'a')

The condition never met, but if i do that in the same interrupt fnction, it does recognize the character.

I am using MPLAB X v5.2 with XC8 compiler. The problem is not the bluetooth or the app used because i have used it before with arduino.

```
                               MAIN CODE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pic18f4550.h>
#include "Configuration_Header_File.h"
#include "LCD_16x2_8-bit_Header_File.h"

void USART_Init(int);

#define F_CPU 8000000/64

char data;

void __interrupt(low_priority) ISR(void)
{
  while(RCIF==0);
  data=RCREG;

  LCD_Char(data);

  while(TXIF==0); 
  if(data=='b')
    TXREG='b';
  if(data=='a')
      TXREG='a';


}

void main()
{
OSCCON=0x72;
MSdelay(10);
LCD_Init();
USART_Init(9600);    
LCD_String_xy(1,0,"Receive");
LCD_Command(0xC0);
while(1){

       if(data=='c')                         /* THIS IS WHAT IS WRONG */
      TXREG='c';
    }
    }



    void USART_Init(int baud_rate)
{   
float temp;
TRISC6=0;           /*Make Tx pin as output*/
TRISC7=1;           /*Make Rx pin as input*/
temp=(((float)(F_CPU)/(float)baud_rate)-1);     
SPBRG=(int)temp;    /*baud rate=9600 SPBRG=(F_CPU /(64*9600))-1*/
TXSTA=0x20;         /*TX enable; */
RCSTA=0x90;         /*RX enanle and serial port enable*/
INTCONbits.GIE=1;   /*Enable Global Interrupt */
INTCONbits.PEIE=1;  /*Enable Peripheral Interrupt */
PIE1bits.RCIE=1;    /*Enable Receive Interrupt*/
PIE1bits.TXIE=1;    /*Enable Transmit Interrupt*/
}
```

As you can see in the code, the conditions inside the interrupt function works, because if i send an 'a' via bluettoth (APP), an 'a' is what i received in the same APP, and same with a 'b', but, when i received a 'c', nothing happens. So i guess that the problem is how is declare the variable "data" or something related to that variable, i have not tried to make it global but i am pretty sure there have to be a better solution. Maybe the content in "data" is erased when the interrupt is done.

I expect the "data" content to be available in the main code but i do not know why it is only recognize in the USART interrupt function.

I would appreciate all your help.

Comment: The code itself seems to be not good, if the UART is receiving a continuous stream of bytes, the ISR will be executed again and again without executing the main function so your code at least won't work under this condition. You need to push the received data into a queue and pull data from the queue in the main function and of course you need to protect the queue with locks(disabling interrupt).

Comment: I see, but i send the characters (bytes) via bluetooth so is not continous, the problem is that when i send an 'a' or 'b', it detects the character but with 'c' (main code) it doesn't

Comment: To locate the problem, first remove other factor, so you can first disable interrupt and do all the RX/TX job in the main loop to see what you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the received data in a FIFO, or other buffering solution for use in the main 'thread'.

The idea is to keep buffering input bytes continously from your ISR and while grabbing  the input at your leisure from the main loop.

Here's an example of a simple COM port solution...  I have not tested it, but it shows the minimal steps needed for an echo application.

```
char rx_buffer[16];
char tx_buffer[16];

_fifo_t rx_fifo;   // need 2 buffers, one for sending, and one for receiving.
_fifo_t tx_fifo;

void __interrupt(low_priority) ISR(void)
{
    // never wait for a flag to becom set or reset within an ISR.  the ISR will be 
    // called automatically when the 
    while (RCIF)
    {
        data=RCREG;
        LCD_Char(data);  // you should considfer moving this out o the ISR.
        FifoPutByte(&rx_fifo, data); // check for overruns is handled by the fifo module.
    }

    while (TXIE && TXIF && !FifoEmpty(&tx_fifo))
         TXREG = FifoGetByte(&tx_fifo);

    if (FifoEmpty(&tx_fifo))  // if no more data to send, disable TX interrupt.
         TXIE = 0;
}

int COM_Transmit(char c)
{
    if (!FifoPutByte(&tx_fifo, c))
        return 0;                    // buffer is full!

    TXIE = 1;  // enable UART TX interrupts

    // now comes the tricky part, you need to 'prime' the transmission of bytes 
    // in the transmit fifo. This operation MUST be done 
    // with interrupts disabled.

    if (TXIF)  // can only be true if TX interrupts are not kicking in.
    {
        PEIE = 0;  // disable peripheral interrupts
        TXREG = FifoGetByte(&tx_fifo); // clears TXIF
        PEIE = 1;  // enable peripheral inrerrupts

        // ISR will be called when UART is done sending the byte in TXREG.
    }
}

void main()
{
    /* initialization code... */

    FifoInit(&rx_fifo, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer));
    FifoInit(&tx_fifo, tx_buffer, sizeof(tx_buffer));

    while(1) 
    {
        // simple UART echo code

        while (!FifoEmpty(&rx_fifo) && !FifoFull(&tx_fifo))
            COM_Transmit(FifoGetByte(&rx_fifo));

        /* doing the other stuff that your controller must do may take some time */
        /* You must make sure that rx_buffer is large enough to capture any bytes */
        /* that could be received during this delay, at 9600 bauds, count 1ms per char */
        MSdelay(15);  // for example...  A larger processing time will warrant larger buffer size for rx_fifo.  
    }
}
```

include file:

```
#ifndef _fifo_h
#define _fifo_h
/* *****************************************************************************
 *
 *  file: fifo.h
 *
 *  Simple byte fifo definitions.
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

#define FIFO_DEBUG  0

typedef struct _fifo_t
{
    volatile unsigned char* pHead;          //  head of data to extract.
    volatile unsigned char* pTail;          //  tail of data for insertion.
    unsigned char* pStart;                          //  start of buffer.
    unsigned char* pEnd;                                //  end of buffer.
    volatile unsigned int nOverruns;        //  overrun counter, in bytes.
    volatile unsigned int nUnderruns;       //  underrun counter, in bytes.
#ifdef FIFO_DEBUG
        volatile unsigned int nWaterMark;   //  Water mark indicating the maximum number of bytes ever held.
#endif
} fifo_t;


void FifoInit(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int len);
void FifoReset(fifo_t* fifo);
int FifoEmpty(fifo_t* fifo);
unsigned int FifoGetFreeSpace(fifo_t* fifo);

// returns nuèmber of bytes available for GET op
unsigned int FifoGetCount(fifo_t* fifo);

// returns total buffer length
unsigned int FifoGetSize(fifo_t* fifo);

// returns the number of bytes in overrun
unsigned int FifoPut(fifo_t* fifo, const void* data, unsigned int len);

//  return the number of bytes copied to data buffer.
unsigned int FifoGet(fifo_t* fifo, void* data, unsigned int len);

//  returns negative value if fifo was empty
int FifoGetByte(fifo_t* fifo);

// returns non zetro value on success.
int FifoPutByte(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned char c);


// returns a contiguous buffer inside fifo, the length of contiguous part is returned in availLen. 
//  caller is responsible for advancing get/put pointer when the data is consumed.
unsigned char* FifoGetContiguousPutBuffer(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int reqLen, unsigned int* availLen);
unsigned char* FifoGetContiguousGetBuffer(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int reqLen, unsigned int* availLen);

// - peeks at data inside fifo, with optional offset from GET pointer, 
//   the length of contiguous part is returned in availLen. 
// - buffer must be large enough to hold reqLen bytes.
// - the value returned is either a direct pointer to fifo buffer, if the data is contuguous, or buffer.
//    if the data was copied to it, or NULL if the data is not avialable in buffer.
// - caller is responsible for advancing get/put pointer when the data is consumed.
void* FifoPeekBuffer(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int offset, unsigned int reqLen, void* buffer);

// - Modifies a single byte at offset from GET pointer.
// - returns non-zero if successful.
char FifoPoke(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int offset, unsigned char c);

// NOTE: interrupts should be disabled around calls to this function.
void FifoSetCount(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int count);

unsigned int FifoAdvancePutPtr(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int len);
unsigned int FifoAdvanceGetPtr(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int len);

#endif
```

.c module:

```
/* *****************************************************************************
 *
 *  file: fifo.c
 *
 *  Simple byte fifo definitions.
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

#include <string.h> //  memcpy()
#include "fifo.h"

void FifoInit(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int len)
{
    fifo->pStart = (unsigned char*)(buffer);
    fifo->pEnd = (unsigned char*)((buffer) + (len));
    fifo->pHead = (unsigned char*)(buffer);
    fifo->pTail = (unsigned char*)(buffer);
    fifo->nOverruns = 0;
#ifdef FIFO_DEBUG
    fifo->nWaterMark = 0;
#endif
}

void FifoReset(fifo_t* fifo)
{
    fifo->pHead = fifo->pStart;
    fifo->pTail = fifo->pStart;
    fifo->nOverruns = 0;
}

int FifoEmpty(fifo_t* fifo)
{
    return (fifo->pHead == fifo->pTail);
}

unsigned int FifoGetFreeSpace(fifo_t* fifo)
{
    return ((fifo->pEnd - fifo->pStart) - FifoGetCount(fifo)) - 1;
}

unsigned int FifoGetCount(fifo_t* fifo)
{
    unsigned char* pHead, * pTail;
    unsigned int nResult;

    pHead = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead;
    pTail = (unsigned char*)fifo->pTail;

    if (pTail >= pHead)
    {
        nResult = pTail - pHead;
    }
    else
    {
        nResult = (pTail - fifo->pStart) + (fifo->pEnd - pHead);
    }

    return nResult;
}

unsigned int FifoGetSize(fifo_t* fifo)
{
    return fifo->pEnd - fifo->pStart;
}

unsigned int FifoPut(fifo_t* fifo, const void* data, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int nMax, nLeft;
    unsigned char* pTail, * pHead;
    const unsigned char* p;

    nLeft = (len);
    p = (const unsigned char*)data;

    while(nLeft)
    {
        pHead = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead;
        if (pHead > fifo->pTail)
        {
            nMax = (pHead - fifo->pTail) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            nMax = fifo->pEnd - fifo->pTail;
        }

        if (nMax > nLeft)
        {
            nMax = nLeft;
        }

        if (!nMax)
        {
            fifo->nOverruns += nLeft;
            break;
        }

        memcpy((void*)fifo->pTail, p, nMax);

        pTail = (unsigned char*)fifo->pTail + nMax;
        if (pTail >= fifo->pEnd)
        {
            pTail = fifo->pStart;
        }
        fifo->pTail = pTail;
        p += nMax;
        nLeft -= nMax;
    }
#ifdef FIFO_DEBUG
    nMax = FifoGetCount(fifo);
    if (nMax > fifo->nWaterMark)
    {
        fifo->nWaterMark = nMax;
    }
#endif
    return nLeft;
}

unsigned int FifoGet(fifo_t* fifo, void* data, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int nMax, nLeft;
    unsigned char* p, * pTail, * pHead;

    nLeft = (len);
    p = (unsigned char*)(data);

    while(nLeft)
    {
        pTail = (unsigned char*)fifo->pTail;
        if (pTail >= fifo->pHead)
        {
            nMax = pTail - fifo->pHead;
        }
        else
        {
            nMax = fifo->pEnd - fifo->pHead;
        }

        if (!nMax)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (nMax > nLeft)
        {
            nMax = nLeft;
        }

        memcpy(p, (void*)fifo->pHead, nMax);

        pHead = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead + nMax;
        if (pHead >= fifo->pEnd)
        {
            pHead = fifo->pStart;
        }
        fifo->pHead = pHead;
        p += nMax;
        nLeft -= nMax;
    }
    return len - nLeft;
}

int FifoPutByte(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned char c)
{
    int result = 0;

    if (FifoGetFreeSpace(fifo))
    {
        unsigned char* pTail = (unsigned char*)fifo->pTail;

        *pTail++ = c;

        if (pTail >= fifo->pEnd)
        {
            pTail = fifo->pStart;
        }

        fifo->pTail = pTail;

        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}


int FifoGetByte(fifo_t* fifo)
{
    int result = -1;
    if (fifo->pHead != fifo->pTail)
    {
        unsigned char* pHead = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead;

        result = *(fifo->pHead);

        if (++pHead >= fifo->pEnd)
        {
            pHead = fifo->pStart;
        }

        fifo->pHead = pHead;
    }
    return result;
}

unsigned char* FifoGetContiguousPutBuffer(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int reqLen, unsigned int* availLen)
{
    unsigned int nMax;
    unsigned char* pHead;

    pHead = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead;

    if (pHead > fifo->pTail)
    {
        nMax = (pHead - fifo->pTail) - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        nMax = fifo->pEnd - fifo->pTail;
        if (pHead == fifo->pStart)
        {
            --nMax;
        }
    }

    if (nMax > reqLen)
    {
        nMax = reqLen;
    }

    *availLen = nMax;

    return (unsigned char*)fifo->pTail;
}

unsigned char* FifoGetContiguousGetBuffer(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int reqLen, unsigned int* availLen)
{
    unsigned int nMax;
    unsigned char* pTail;

    pTail = (unsigned char*)fifo->pTail;
    if (pTail >= fifo->pHead)
    {
        nMax = pTail - fifo->pHead;
    }
    else
    {
        nMax = fifo->pEnd - fifo->pHead;
    }

    if (nMax > reqLen)
    {
        nMax = reqLen;
    }

    *availLen = nMax;

    return (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead;
}

void* FifoPeekBuffer(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int offset, unsigned int reqLen, void* buffer)
{
    void* result;

    result = NULL;

    if ((reqLen + offset) <= FifoGetCount(fifo))
    {
        unsigned char* pHead, * pTail;

        pHead = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead + offset;

        if (pHead >= fifo->pEnd)
        {
            pHead -= (fifo->pEnd - fifo->pStart);
        }

        pTail = pHead + reqLen;

        if (pTail <= fifo->pEnd)
        {
            result = pHead;
        }
        else
        {
            // need to copy, as requested data wraps around 
            unsigned char* p;
            unsigned int n;

            p = (unsigned char*)buffer;
            n = fifo->pEnd - pHead;

            memcpy(p, pHead, n);
            memcpy(p + n, fifo->pStart, reqLen - n);

            result = buffer;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

char FifoPoke(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int offset, unsigned char c)
{
    unsigned char* p;
    char result = 0;

    if (offset < FifoGetCount(fifo))
    {
        p = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead + offset;

        if (p >= fifo->pEnd)
        {
            p -= (fifo->pEnd - fifo->pStart);
        }

        *p = c;

        result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}

unsigned int FifoAdvancePutPtr(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned char* pTail;

    n = FifoGetFreeSpace(fifo);

    if (len > n)
    {
        fifo->nOverruns += (len - n);       
        len = n;
    }

    pTail = (unsigned char*)fifo->pTail + len;

    while (pTail >= fifo->pEnd)
    {
        pTail -= (fifo->pEnd - fifo->pStart);
    }

    fifo->pTail = pTail;

#ifdef FIFO_DEBUG
    n = FifoGetCount(fifo);
    if (n > fifo->nWaterMark)
    {
        fifo->nWaterMark = n;
    }
#endif

    return len;
}

unsigned int FifoAdvanceGetPtr(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned char* pHead;

    n = FifoGetCount(fifo);
    if (len > n)
    {
        fifo->nUnderruns += (len - n);
        len = n;
    }

    pHead = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead + len;

    while (pHead >= fifo->pEnd)
    {
        pHead -= (fifo->pEnd - fifo->pStart);
    }

    fifo->pHead = pHead;

    return len;
}

void FifoSetCount(fifo_t* fifo, unsigned int count)
{
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned char* pTail;

    n = FifoGetSize(fifo);
    if (count > n)
    {
        fifo->nOverruns += (count - n);     
        count = n;
    }

    pTail = (unsigned char*)fifo->pHead + count;

    while (pTail >= fifo->pEnd)
    {
        pTail -= (fifo->pEnd - fifo->pStart);
    }

    fifo->pTail = pTail;

#ifdef FIFO_DEBUG
    n = FifoGetCount(fifo);
    if (n > fifo->nWaterMark)
    {
        fifo->nWaterMark = n;
    }
#endif
}
```

Note that this fifo struct is not the most efficient for a small PIC, but it should work fine nonetheless.  Writing your own FIFO is a very good exercise. The one above is taken from production code, I think I last used it on an STM32. It's also been used in production on dsPIC and on Arduino.